# Can we get fluid design with Xamarin.Forms for UWP?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, win-universal-app

Can we get the fluid design in Windows 10 UWP app with Xamarin.Forms?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic

Comment: since the big info box at the top of the page says "this hasn't been released" I would guess the answer is "no"

Answer (score 1):

Jason is technically right since the feature isn't publically released yet. However, you should be able to try it already if you're in the Windows Insider Preview program. This is what you need:

1. Latest version of Visual Studio (2017, 15.3)
2. Latest Windows 10 Insider Preview SDK (probably 16267)
3. Latest version of the .NET UWP NuGet Package

You can check that you have the correct version if `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush` is accessible.

---

**Using with Xamarin.Forms:** I haven't tried this myself but technically it should be possible. You'll need to roll out a custom renderer for the UWP platform where you define the Acrylic brush and add it to a control (Grid in this example). You also need to make sure to check that the `XamlCompositionBrushBase` is present and have a fallback for the case where it's not.

```
if(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.XamlCompositionBrushBase"))
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush myBrush = new 
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBrush();
    myBrush.BackgroundSource = 
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop;
    myBrush.TintColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37);
    myBrush.FallbackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37);
    myBrush.TintOpacity = 0.6;

    grid.Fill = myBrush;
}
else
{ 
    SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 202, 24, 37));

    grid.Fill = myBrush;
}
```

This code is taken straight from the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic) you linked to but it should work as is in the custom renderer.

*Please notice, that even if you get it to work, there might be major changes to the API and you'll have to rework your solution again and again.*

Comment: Have you try ? What is the result ?